# propagate changes down a column

Tags: r

I would like to use dplyr to go through a dataframe row by row, and if `A == 0`, then set `B` to the value of `B` in the previous row, otherwise leave it unchanged. However, I want "the value of `B` in the previous row" to refer to the previous row during the computation, not before the computation began, because the value may have changed -- in other words, I'd like changes to propagate downwards. For example, with the following data:

`dat <- data.frame(A=c(1,0,0,0,1),B=c(0,1,1,1,1))`

```
A B
1 0
0 1
0 1
0 1
1 1
```

I would like the result of the computation to be:

`result <- data.frame(A=c(1,0,0,0,1),B=c(0,0,0,0,1))`

```
A B
1 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
1 1
```

If I use something like `result <- dat %>% mutate(B = ifelse(A==0,lag(B),B)` then changes won't propagate downwards: result$B will be equal to c(0,0,1,1,1), not c(0,0,0,0,1).

More generally, how do you use dplyr::mutate to create a column that depends on itself (as it updates during the computation, not a copy of what it was before)?

Comment: All `mutate` does is provide an interface to add a column to a data frame - how that column is defined is up to you. There is nothing `dplyr` or `mutate`-specific about this question.

Comment: Are we to assume that the data only contains 0s and 1s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you want a "last observation carried forward" approach. The most common R implementation is `zoo::na.locf` which fills in `NA` values with the last observation. All we need to do to use it in this case is to first set to `NA` all the B values that we want to fill in:

```
mutate(dat, 
       B = ifelse(A == 0, NA, B),
       B = zoo::na.locf(B))
# A B
# 1 1 0
# 2 0 0
# 3 0 0
# 4 0 0
# 5 1 1
```

As to my comment, do note that the only thing `mutate` does is add the column to the data frame. We could do it just as well without mutate:

```
result = dat
result$B = with(result, ifelse(A == 0, NA, B))
result$B = zoo::na.locf(result$B)
```

Whether you use `mutate` or `[` or `$` or any other method to access/add the columns is tangential to the problem.

Comment: if I do this: `set.seed(30)`
`dat <- data.frame(A=sample(0:1,100,replace = TRUE),
                  B=sample(0:1,100,replace = TRUE))` and run your function, I'm getting values of B carried forward in the first block where A == 0.

Comment: I'm also getting an error running the first code with my extended example. I think it's the weird `ifelse` NA bug

Comment: Also try this variation: `transform(dat, B = na.locf(replace(B, A == 0, NA), na.rm = FALSE))` or use `mutate` from dplyr in place of `transform`,

Answer (score 2):

We could use `fill` from `tidyr` after changing the 'B' values to NA that corresponds to 0 in 'A'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
     mutate(B = NA^(!A)*B) %>%
     fill(B)
#  A B
#1 1 0
#2 0 0
#3 0 0
#4 0 0
#5 1 1
```

NOTE: By default, the `.direction` (argument in `fill`) is "down", but it can also take "up" i.e. `fill(B, .direction="up")`

Comment: If the first A is 0, doesn't this generate NA's for B?

Comment: @Shape You can have many edge cases, but I am just following the OP's example and I don't know what will be the output for that scenario

Comment: my impression was that he wanted the field to be left unedited otherwise, that was an assumption though.

Comment: @Shape Also, based on the data in your post, I think we can do a second `fill` i.e. `dat %>%mutate(B = NA^(!A)*B) %>% fill(B) %>% fill(B, .direction = "up")` to get the same output as in your post

Comment: @Shape i.e. `all.equal(lapply(res[1:2], as.character), lapply(res1, as.character), check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE`

Comment: @Shape `res` and `res1` are the output from your soltuion and mine

Comment: Ah, okay, but doesn't that only work in this case because B at the end of the first group is equal to the value we want for be in the first few rows? Aren't we using a priori knowledge?

Comment: @Shape If there is no NA, the second `fill` doesn't do anything.  I don't know what you are implying

Comment: In my 2nd example, with 15 rows of data, filling up sets the first 6 rows to 1. My solution leaves those values unchanged as 1,0,1,1,0,0. Since there is no previous 'A == 1' which should override the existing values.

Comment: @Shape Okay, so you changed your example.  As I said earlier, I am using the OP's example and I don't know what other patterns he/she has.

Comment: @Shape As I read the OP's description `if A == 0, then set B to the value of B in the previous row`,  in your new example A is 0 for the first element and there is no previous row..  It is not clear what he wanted in that case.

Comment: Yeah, I think we need clarification here, you're right, as he wrote it mine is currently wrong as well, I should actually just always take the first value in my groups, not only if there's an A==1 precursor.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using grouping, and `rleid` (Run length encoding id) from `data.table`. I think it should be faster than the `zoo` solution, since zoo relies on doing multiple revs and a cumsum. And `rleid` is blazing fast

Basically, we only want the last value of the previous group, so we create a grouping variable based on the diff vector of the rleid and add that to the `rleid` if `A == 1`. Then we group and take the first B-value of the group for every case where `A == 0`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dat <- data.frame(A=c(1,0,0,0,1),B=c(0,1,1,1,1))

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(grp = data.table::rleid(A),
         grp = ifelse(A == 1, grp + c(diff(grp),0),grp)) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(B = ifelse(A == 0, B[1],B)) # EDIT: Always carry forward B on A == 0

dat

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: grp [2]

      A     B   grp
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     2
2     0     0     2
3     0     0     2
4     0     0     2
5     1     1     3
```

EDIT: Here's an example with a longer dataset so we can really see the behavior: (Also, switched, it should be if all `A != 1` not if not all `A == 1`

```
set.seed(30)
dat <- data.frame(A=sample(0:1,15,replace = TRUE),
                  B=sample(0:1,15,replace = TRUE))

> dat
   A B
1  0 1
2  0 0
3  0 1
4  0 1
5  0 0
6  0 0
7  1 1
8  0 0
9  1 0
10 0 0
11 0 0
12 0 0
13 1 0
14 1 1
15 0 0
```

Result:

```
 Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
Groups: grp [5]

       A     B   grp
   <int> <int> <dbl>
1      0     1     1
2      0     1     1
3      0     1     1
4      0     1     1
5      0     1     1
6      0     1     1
7      1     1     3
8      0     1     3
9      1     0     5
10     0     0     5
11     0     0     5
12     0     0     5
13     1     0     6
14     1     1     7
15     0     1     7
```

Comment: After microbenchmarking on these small sets, this is, interestingly, slower than the zoo solution, I wonder if it would be faster in data.table over a large number of rows though, I'll test.